# Add a style in css depending on the value of the field with django

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm trying to style my line of code:

```
<td class="{% if inven < 10 %}color-green-primary{% else %}color-red-primary{% endif %}">{{inven.quantityInventory}}</span></td>
```

It should change color depending on the value that is presented.
The bad thing is that it always shows it to me in red (in else). what am I doing wrong?

**html**

```
                             {% for inven in inventory %}
                                <tr>
                                   <td><strong>{{inven.codigoInventory}}</strong></td>
                                   <td>{{inven.descriptionInventory}}</td>
                                   <td>${{inven.unitPriceInventory}}</td>
                                   <td class="{% if inven < 10 %}color-green-primary{% else %}color-red-primary{% endif %}">{{inven.quantityInventory}}</span></td>
                                   <td>{{inven.dealer}}</td>
                                   <td>{{inven.invoiceNumber}}</td>
                                   <td>
                                      <div class="badge bg-soft-danger font-size-12">{{inven.status}}</div>
                                   </td>
                                   <td><a href="{% url 'inventory:inventory_detail' inven.id%}">Detail</a></td>
                                   <td><a href="{% url 'inventory:edit_inventory' inven.id%}">Edit</a></td>
                                   <td><a href="{% url 'inventory:eliminar_inventory' inven.id%}" class="text-danger" >Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def list_inventory(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fromdate=request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        searchresult = Inventory.objects.filter(fecha_registro__range=(fromdate, todate))
        return render(request,'inventory/inventory-list.html',{'inventory':searchresult})

    else:
        displaydata = Inventory.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'inventory/inventory-list.html', {'inventory': displaydata})
```

Comment: What is `inven` or `inventory`? Looks like it might be a model instance but you are comparing it to an int which doesn't look right `inven < 10`

Comment: let me add the view

Comment: Do you want to display the cell green when `inven.quantityInventory` is less than 10?

Comment: yes, the cell or the text can be green

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be comparing against `inven.quantityInventory` not just `inven`. It does not make sense to compare a model instance with an int, compare against an int attribute

```
<td class="{% if inven.quantityInventory < 10 %}color-green-primary{% else %}color-red-primary{% endif %}">{{ inven.quantityInventory }}</span></td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
{% if inven.quantityInventory < 10 %}
<td class="color-green-primary">{{inven.quantityInventory}}</span></td>
{% else %}
<td class="color-red-primary">{{inven.quantityInventory}}</span></td>
{% endif %}
```